# first web service from WSDL with .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I have a WSDL file and I want to create a SOAP server process from that file using visual studio .NET.

Until now I have created a cs file from the WSDL with the following command

**wsdl my.wsdl my.xsd /language:CS /server**

Now I want to start a server process at a custom port (eg port 10000) that will send the responce back to my client after an HTTP post from the client.

How do I proceed. What are the next steps? Any tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should create a web application project in Visual Studio and within that an ASMX file that points the code generated class. If you want to host the web service on port 10000 you simply create an IIS web site running on port 10000 that points to the location of your web application project.

You can check-out this [tutorial](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010430.htm) on how to create an ASMX based web service from scratch - though the tutorial does not use your WSDL first approach... Hope it helps!